# next auth: `useSession` must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider /> -- even with _app.tsx updated

Tags: reactjs, next.js, oauth, next-auth

I am building a nextjs react app and I can't get next auth to work correctly.  My _app.tsx file has the SessionProvider wrapper and I am stumped.  I still see this error when I try to start and navigage to my app:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waJW6.png)

pages/_app.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"
import type { AppProps } from "next/app"

export default function App({ Component, pageProps: {session, ...pageProps} }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
export default NextAuth({
    providers:[
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId:process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID || '',
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET || '',
        }),
    ]

});
```

src/app/page.tsx:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import Login from '../components/Login'


export default function Home() {
  return <Login />
    
}
```

src/components/Login.tsx:

```
'use client';

import { useSession, signIn } from "next-auth/react"


export default function Login() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  if (session) {
    return <h1>Welcome</h1>
  } else {
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

.env file (values redacted):

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=
NEXTAUTH_URL=
```

All articles I've read say adding the SessionProvider wrapper in the _app.tsx should fix this, but it still won't work.  I've also tried blasting the .next file and restarting.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You are only adding the `SessionProvider` component to your _app.tsx file inside your pages directory while the page itself is contained in the app directory. Include the session provider inside your layout file . Generally you shouldn't mix pages and app directory, only if migrating from an old application.

Comment: Thank you!  If I use the layout am I still able to pass the current session into the attribute of the sessionprovider element?  If I don't do this the app doesn't seem to persist the logged in state of the user.

Comment: Yes. You can do the session fetching directly in the component by making it asychronous and executing the same logic in your server side props.